# How to hide source code of angularjs like controllers in web browser?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot

We are using angular JS with spring boot. Everything is working fine but we have some problem as our UI is deployed at different location and Java code is at different. When we inspect in browser, we are able to see our JS source codes and all the controllers in browser. Due to this our complete logic is exposed in browser. Please help us to hide the code or the best way to hide code from browser to secure the application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can not hide the source but you can minify the code.
The sense of javascript is to download the script into the browser and run it there.
You can also use node.js to run important code on the backend.